# How to obtain the aggregate value of items in subfolders as a column

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

I'm using MySQL.

**FOLDER TABLE**

| id | parent_folder_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 |

**AUDIO_FILE_TABLE**

| id | parent_folder_id | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 20 |
| 3 | 4 | 20 |
| 4 | 3 | 30 |
| 5 | 4 | 10 |
| 6 | 4 | 20 |
| 7 | 2 | 20 |
| 8 | 2 | 20 |

I would like to have an output to get the sum of duration (include all subfolders), but not sure how to do it.
Folder 1 have subfolders [2, 3] at 1st level and then [4, 7, 8] at 2nd level, and then [5, 6] at 3rd level. So all folders are [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] which include all the audios, giving the sum 10 + 20 + 20 + 30 + 10 + 20 + 20 + 20 = 150.

Folder 2 have subfolders [2] at 1st level and then [4, 7, 8] at 2nd level, and then [5, 6] at 3rd level. So all folders are [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] which include audios [3, 5, 6, 7, 8], giving the sum 20 + 10 + 20 + 20 + 20 = 90.

Folder 3 have no subfolder. So all folders are [3] which include audios [4], giving the sum 30.

**OUTPUT**

| id | parent_folder_id | total_duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 150 |
| 2 | 1 | 90 |
| 3 | 4 | 30 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive `cte`:

```sql
with recursive cte(id, id1) as (
   select f.id, f.id from folders f
   union all
   select c.id, f.id from cte c join folders f on f.parent_folder_id = c.id1
)
select k.*, f.parent_folder_id from 
   (select c.id, sum(a.duration) from cte c join audio_files a on c.id1 = a.parent_folder_id group by c.id) k 
join audio_files f on f.id = k.id
```